# Define a column as nullable in model class (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ado.net

I need to define a column in a model class as nullable. In .NET Core, adding a `?` to the datatype declaration would have done so. But what can I do in this situation?

The model I created is

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientEmail { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public string PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public string SecondaryContact { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Required]
    public string Software { get; set; }
    public DateTime ContractDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AMCDate { get; set; }
    public decimal ContractAmount { get; set; }
    public string AnydeskID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

`string.Empty` seems to be working for string Datatype but what can I do for `DateTime` and `decimal`?

Furthermore, `DataTime` accepts both date and time, is there any way to get only date as its value?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime and decimal are nonnullable Datatypes. That means they have the default value and for use as nullable you must use '?'.

To get only the date or time you can you these codes

```
 var MyDate = DateTime.Now;
 var MyDay = MyDate.Date;
 var MyTime = MyDate.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default to set a default value. (For DateTime it would be January 1, 0001 00:00:00)

```
public DateTime DateTime {get; set;} =default;
```

Since DateTime is a none nullable type, DateTime will contain the DateTime default value.
If DateTime needs to be nullable, you can do the following:

```
public DateTime? DateTime {get; set;} =default;
```

Now DateTime will be null since null is the default Value for a nullable Type.

If you are using a code first database design, then the column will also automatically be set to be able to conatin null values if you use the ? on a Property (this is true for normally nullable types such as string)

Answer (score 0):

For Nullable Datetime you can use

```
public DateTime? PropertyName {get; set;}
```

For Nullable Decimal

```
public Decimal? PropertyName {get; set;}
```

For Only Date

If you want the standard approach look at the DateTime.Date property which gives just the date portion of a DateTime with the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).